# Package 'build-essential' has no installation candidate

Tags: apt, package-management, 22.04, repository

I've been trying to install build essential on a cloud VM running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-1032-oracle aarch64)

I'm unfortunately, very clueless about ubuntu, but from what I can gather, I'm unable to get build-essential because my apt-get repositories are all (possibly) messed up and I'm not sure how to fix them exactly.

This is a bit "Ask me like I'm five" question. I've got no GUI, so it's all console.

---

Here's the   /etc/apt/source.list

```
  ## Note, this file is written by cloud-init on first boot of an instance
## modifications made here will not survive a re-bundle.
## if you wish to make changes you can:
## a.) add 'apt_preserve_sources_list: true' to /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
##     or do the same in user-data
## b.) add sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.d
## c.) make changes to template file /etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.tmpl

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://eu-frankfurt-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy main restricted
# deb-src http://eu-frankfurt-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://eu-frankfurt-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://eu-frankfurt-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://eu-frankfurt-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy universe
# deb-src http://eu-frankfurt-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy universe
deb http://eu-frankfurt-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-updates universe
# deb-src http://eu-frankfurt-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://eu-frankfurt-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy multiverse
# deb-src http://eu-frankfurt-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy multiverse
deb http://eu-frankfurt-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://eu-frankfurt-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://eu-frankfurt-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://eu-frankfurt-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-            backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security main restricted
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security main restricted
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security universe
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security multiverse
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security multiverse
```

---

This is what I get from running apt-get update
(message was too big to fit)

https://pastebin.com/X39r56GL

Comment: If you're still running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (*I suggest you check*), please apply your security fixes asap, as the .4 upgrades are rolling out now, and .2 shows you've not applied security fixes since Aug-23 if not before.  Is there are reason why you've not applied security fixes? (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/08/11/ubuntu-22-04-3-lts-released/ shows release date of 22.04.3 ISO, but installed systems upgraded before that date).  Do you get any warnings if you `sudo apt update` ??

Comment: You should provide your actual command, and any messages you get via copy/paste (*it's possible still on text only system*) as the package is there for your architecture, ie. `build-essential | 12.9ubuntu3   | jammy         | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x`

Comment: To apply all fixes (including security) on your current release; you do **not** use `do-release-upgrade`, but just `sudo apt update` & ensure there are no warnings, errors or missing lines in the update, then apply the fixes using `sudo apt upgrade`; & in rare cases `sudo apt full-upgrade`. You've not provided that output from `sudo apt update` which points to where the errors are in your sources (sources can be more than `/etc/apt/sources.list` too, but include files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` which is empty on a new/clean install).

Comment: I'm sorry for misunderstanding you at first, I've update the main post with the full output of sudo apt-get update @guiverc

Answer (score 0):

Here is a template for [cloud sources](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/canonical/cloud-init/master/templates/sources.list.ubuntu.tmpl).

To download:

```
 wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/canonical/cloud-init/master/templates/sources.list.ubuntu.tmpl .
```

Make changes, save your original sources.list file then replace it,

e,g: `{{codename}}` replace it with `jammy`.